.htaccess redirect, send last directory as a parameter
I need to redirect domain.com/kiosk/m42 or domain.com/kiosk/m42/ to domain.com/kiosk/?m42 m42 — is a changeable part, it's could be s41, p39 or whatever...
I've tried
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(.*)/kiosk/(\w+)/?$
RewriteRule  ^   %1/kiosk/?%2&%{QUERY_STRING}  [R=301,L]

or
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/kiosk
RewriteRule (.*)/([^/]+)/?$ https://my-bakery.ru/kiosk/?$2 [L,R=301,QSA]

but that doesn't work well. Where am i mistaken?

While not optimal, both the methods you’ve shown should “work”, so there is likely something else going on here. What happens exactly? What other directives do you have? Where exactly have your put this rule? Where is this .htaccess file? (Any other .htaccess files?)

It is unclear what you are trying to do with that  first attempt: the pattern is matched against the path component of the URL. That starts with /kiosk and nothing before that. So what is that first brackets group meant to capture, what is %1 meant to hold? If there is more to the task than what you described here you make it hard for us to offer help. You might want to revise your question to simplify things. There is an "edit" link below your question, use it ...

What do you actually mean by "that doesn't work well"? Does it work or not? If not, then what does that mean exactly? What do you see? Where is that different to what you expected to see?

Your question is a bit vague in the details (I commented on that above), but I assume the following should be what you are looking for:
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&=]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?kiosk/?$ /kiosk/%1 [R=301,L,QSD]

RewriteRule ^/?kiosk/([^/]+)/?$ /kiosk/?$1 [L,QSA]

You can implement such rules in the central http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that (read: if you are using a simple web space provider) you can alternatively use a distributed configuration file (usually called ".htaccess"), but the first option should generally be preferred. If you opt for the alternative you need to make sure that the file is located in the http hosts DocumentRoot folder, that is is readable for the http server process and that the consideration of such rules inside such a file has been enabled by means of the AllowOverride directive.
